# In general, how much is V/V∞ ratio at upper wing surface?

Tags: aerodynamics, theory

Airflow on upper surface is always faster then freestream, in general, how much is airflow speed to freestream speed ratio(V/V∞, max values) at upper wing surface, are we talking about 1.1 to 2 or 2,3,4..?

Is this ratio even  higher at multielement wing at slot outlet where flow is fastest?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pressure coefficient is readily available for several airfoil and angle of attack.

The [following NASA report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19810010497), for example, includes the pressure coefficient for a NACA 23012 airfoil with slotted flap. Let's use the figure 6 at page 35, which shows the pressure coefficient at 8.3° AoA:

[image]

As visible, the "highest" pressure reached is -5.5 close to the nose of the main airfoil.

By definition:

$$C_p=\frac{p-p_{\infty}}{q_{\infty}}=1-(\frac{V}{V_{\infty}})²$$

where the last relationship is true for subsonic speeds. Substituting our $C_p$ of -5.5 we get:

$$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}=\sqrt{1+5.5}=2.55$$

which is the value you were looking for.

Comment: How much is lowest  Cp without active blowing?

Comment: On the paper I linked there are other interesting plots of $C_p$

Comment: More than doubling at only 8.3 degrees alpha. Wow! I wonder how much effect supersonic flow has on induced drag.  Could **this** be the source of the "Laminar flow wing" craze.

Answer (score 3):

You can get very low Cp's.  However, you still have to recover back to Cp=0, so if your peak -Cp is very low, you end up with a stronger adverse pressure gradient and end up with separation.

Consequently, the lowest peak Cp's are typically seen in high lift applications.

If you know the freestream Mach number, you can use the compressible definition of the pressure coefficient to determine at which Cp the flow will become sonic -- this is usually called the critical pressure coefficient.  For this high lift flow (with $M_\infty<0.2$ I think), the peak Cp is very near to sonic.

This kind of problem is very challenging to solve (among many other challenges), CFD codes that are 'good at' compressible flow usually have difficulty converging when the flow is mostly incompressible.  Incompressible codes will ignore compressibility and will get the wrong answer.  A flow like this is mostly incompressible, but has small pockets where compressibility is important.

[image: Pressure distribution around high lift airfoil.]

Comment: Cp -17?  But this must be with some active blowing or?

Comment: Nope.  Just really low freestream velocity and a 20deg angle of attack without stalling.  This is from AGARD AR-303, Case A2.

Comment: I thought that this is impossible. This airflow is 4.24x faster then freestream..

Comment: You're likely using the incompressible definition of Cp.  Even though the freestream here is quite slow (less than M 0.2 if I recall), compressibility effects are important with this much acceleration, so your ratio might be a bit off.  But the point remains, large accelerations are possible.  Why did you think otherwise?

Comment: I did some digging.  This wind tunnel test was done at 67 m/s and very nearly at sea level conditions (not specified in the docs, but it checks out).  That works out to M=0.197.  Which means the flow is sonic at Cp=-16.84 -- so the pressure peak in this case is actually supersonic.  The peak velocity is more than 5x freestream.

Comment: we can't go below   -101 325 Pa, how much will be -17 Cp, in Pa?

Comment: @user628075: you have the equation for $C_p$ (in my answer) and all the needed values (in the comment by Rob McDonald): try it out 

Comment: @sophit static pressure is 63 168 Pa, so suction is -38156 Pa, 0.38bar

Comment: Just to add a little more data.  The tunnel flow conditions for this test are listed as V=67m/s and q=2.75kPa.  They don't list temperature, pressure, or density.  You can back density out of these two values - or just multiply Cp by q to get a deltaP.  -17*2.75=-46.75kPa

Comment: @RobMcDonald delta P is - 0.46bar ,this is huge suction!

Comment: @user628075 Yup.  And the lift coefficient is over 4!

Comment: @sophit dose your formula works for supersonic flow?

Comment: @user628075: it's written in the answer...

Comment: @sophit why then we used this formula for supersonic speeds in Rob post?

Comment: "*compressibility effects are important with this much acceleration, so your ratio might be* ***a bit off. But the point remains***, *large accelerations are possible*" (cit). This site is called Stackexchange, not Journal of Fluid Dynamics 